# What’s a plausible explanation for the inconsistent progression of the Galactic Republic?

Tags: star-wars, history-of

I know this is a bit silly to treat the Star Wars galaxy so seriously but I look at the universe from a Watsonian point of view as opposed to Doylist.

So. I was reading the Timeline of Galactic History page on Wookieepedia. In Canon these events happened.

Before 25,000 BBY

Various species develop a hyperdrive

25,000 BBY

The Galactic Republic is formed

1000 BBY
The Republic reforms after major wars with various factions and then the Sith

200 BBY
High Republic era. Noticeable difference between the society from then till the Prequels. Beings are just starting to explore the Outer Rim

32 BBY
The Prequel Era. The galaxy is settled

0 ABY
Original Trilogy era

34 ABY
Sequel era

Now aliens invented the hyperdrive before 25,000 and had it for 24,000 years. The Republic reformed. Then High Republic. Then the movies.

There are major changes in technological development over the course of the 3 movie trilogies which is only about 60 years.

What is a plausible explanation for why there was so much change in tech and science in 6 decades in the galaxy but the civilization remained static for 24ish centuries after developing FTL travel?

Comment: I'd suggest that the premise of your question is flawed. What data are you using to form the hypothesis that nothing happened for 24 millennia? And what massive technological leaps do you believe took place over the course of the nine movies that weren't simply larger iterations of what came before?

Comment: Well I don’t have an answer to that but once you develop superluminal travel and then you remain basically the same for millennia and then within 60 years everything changes; it’s kinda strange.

Comment: How do you know hyperdrive hasn’t been made faster, cheaper, smaller, etc.? What about other inventions? Air travel was invented 100 years ago on earth and it’s still the fastest way to travel - nothing has changed about that one fact. But things have changed about air travel and also many other things not related to travel have changed and been invented. Imagine saying "the wheel was invented 10,000 years ago and then nothing changed after that" simply because we still use wheels.

Comment: Yes. I know some things don’t change BUT when you crack FTL and then 24 millennia later; you still just have FTL and then over the course of 60 years; everything changes. It’s just odd.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a lot of exploration, expansion, and war that happens between 25,000 and 1,000 BBY:

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history

The Republic is certainly not static during that time.